# Contar veces que aparece un valor en un array

Tags: java, array

Dado un array de n enteros, contar el número de veces que aparece un valor
determinado. Resolver el problema con un algoritmo recursivo

- `int contar (int [] array, int valor, int posInici)`
- `array`: array con los valores.
- `valor`: valor buscar.
- `posInici`: Posición inicial donde empezamos a buscar.

Os paso el código que tengo hecho:

```
package tema2;

public class Problema3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array={3,12,314,1234,3};
        int valor=3;
        int posInici=1;

        Problema3 programa = new Problema3();

        programa.comptar(array,valor,posInici);
        System.out.println(posInici);
    }

    public static int comptar(int [] array,int valor,int posInici) {
        int j=0;
        if(posInici == array.length) {  
             j++;
        }
        if(valor == array[posInici]) {
             return array valor posInici + 1;
        } 
     }  
 }
```

Comment: esto no compila, no? donde estas llevando la cuenta de cuantas veces encontraste el numero que buscabas?

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver está haciendo su tarea pero tiene dificultades para culminarla, por eso viene al sitio. Y nosotros debemos guiarle a resolver esos problemas (que es distinto a resolver el ejercicio por él/ella)

Comment: (￣□￣;) @LuiggiMendoza con la última [edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/58867/revisions), la pregunta se hizo de baja calidad.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza He revertido la edición, cualquier cosa puede volverla a poner.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas..

Vamos a desarmar tu problema por pedazos, pero no voy a escribirte la solución. Si darte tips para llegar a ella.

Lo primero que debes pensar es que tu función recursiva debe devolver algo... algo que le sirva al paso anterior.. que tal si devuelves si encontraste lo que buscabas o no?

aparte de eso, tu función recursiva debe saber cuando llego al final.. o sea que tiene que terminar en algún momento...

fíjate que con esos dos tips, ya puedes replantear lo que estas escribiendo y buscando.

Ve un paso a la vez si queres. primero fíjate que la función termine.. y después fíjate como hacer para contar..

P.D: tu return esta mal ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int comptar(int [] array,intvalor,int posInici) {
            if(posInici<array.lentgh){
            if(valor==array[posInici])
            return 1+comptar(array,valor,posInici+1);
            else
            return 0+ comptar(array,valor, posInici+1);
   } 
    return 0;
    }
```

con este método puedes contar cuantas veces aparece un valor en el arreglo. 
Tu método está mal por los siguientes motivos:

- Tu contador se encuentra dentro del método y al inicio, por lo que
  cada que se entra al método su valor se vuelve cero entonces eso hace
  que no sirva para contar.
- En tu return se debe de volver a llamar el método, ya que en eso
  consiste la recursividad.